# inserting multiple columns below another in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Here is my data.

```r
dat<-read.table(text=" MP1  MP2 MP3 N1  N2  N3  WP1 WP2 WP3

A   A   A   Y   Y   Y   10  11  11
A   B   A   Y   Y   Y   10  11  11
B   B   A   Y   Y   Y   10  10  11
A   B   A   Y   Y   Y   11  11  10
B   B   A   Y   Y   Y   10  10  11
B   B   A   N   Y   Y   11  10  10
B   C   A   Y   Y   Y   11  11  11
C   C   B   Y   Y   N   10  11  10
B   C   B   Y   Y   Y   11  11  11
B   C   B   Y   N   Y   10  11  11
",header=TRUE)
```

I want to get this table. Indeed I want to get three columns instead of nine columns. These columns are named as follows:

```
MP  N   WP
A   Y   10
A   Y   10
B   Y   10
A   Y   11
B   Y   10
B   N   11
B   Y   11
C   Y   10
B   Y   11
B   Y   10
A   Y   11
B   Y   11
B   Y   10
B   Y   11
B   Y   10
B   Y   10
C   Y   11
C   Y   11
C   Y   11
C   N   11
A   Y   11
A   Y   11
A   Y   11
A   Y   10
A   Y   11
A   Y   10
A   Y   11
B   N   10
B   Y   11
B   Y   11
```

I have tried this:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(MP=unlist(dat, use.names = FALSE))
```

But, not sure why it does not work. I also used

```
dat2 <- data.frame(MP = c(dat[,"MP"], dat[,"N"],dat[,WP])))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is `pivot_longer`, specify the `cols` argument as `everything()` (as we are using all the columns), also the separation in column names is between the numbers and the uppercase letters, so we can use a regex lookaround to do the split at that junction

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>%      
   pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c( ".value", "grp"), 
        names_sep="(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
   select(-grp)

# A tibble: 30 x 3
#   MP    N        WP
#   <fct> <fct> <int>
# 1 A     Y        10
# 2 A     Y        11
# 3 A     Y        11
# 4 A     Y        10
# 5 B     Y        11
# 6 A     Y        11
# 7 B     Y        10
# 8 B     Y        10
# 9 A     Y        11
#10 A     Y        11
# … with 20 more rows
```

---

Or with `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(dat), measure = patterns("^MP", "^N", "^WP"),
        value.name = c("MP", "N","WP"))[, variable := NULL][]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another base R approach that preserves the factors:

```
names(dat) <- c(rep("MP", 3), rep("N", 3), rep("WP", 3))
rdat2 <- rbind(dat[, c(1, 4, 7)], dat[, c(2, 5, 8)], dat[, c(3, 6, 9)])
str(rdat2)
# 'data.frame': 30 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ MP: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 3 2 2 ...
#  $ N : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
# $ WP: int  10 10 10 11 10 11 11 10 11 10 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution using base R is:

```
as.data.frame(sapply(c("MP", "N", "WP"), function(x) unlist(dat[grep(x, names(dat))]), simplify = FALSE))
```